# Creating an android DialogFragment in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hello i am trying to create a DialogFragment in Android. The rest of the code works well- i think; except for when i call the AlertDialog.Builder() method, i get an error that says:"the method Builder is undefined for the type AlertDialog. here is my entire code, i hope that someone can help me fix it.
Here is my code below:

`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DialogFragmentEx extends DialogFragment {

    static DialogFragmentEx newInstance(String title) {
        DialogFragmentEx fragment = new DialogFragmentEx();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String title = getArguments().getString("title");

        return AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((DialogFragmentExampleActivity)
                            getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((DialogFragmentExampleActivity) getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                        }
                }).create();
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build your Dialog when you are extending to **DialogFragment**. Your code is good enough.

You only need to use below code to display your dialog.

```
DialogFragmentEx alertdFragment = new DialogFragmentEx ();
// Show Alert DialogFragment
alertdFragment.show(context, "Alert Dialog Fragment");
```

Check this [Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-dialogfragment-tutorial/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot initiating `Builder`, so change your codes to:

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
       .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         ... ...

       ).create();
```

Hope this help!